# Using ffmpeg for capturing (and recording) audio and video from decklink card using Windows 7

Tags: video, ffmpeg, sdi

Im new with ffmpeg. I am trying to capture the video + audio from Decklink capture device. However I had some problems, I don’t know which stream using for my current video + audio source that connected to the decklink card's SDI port. Could someone tell me how to find out the streaming information.

Here is my information:

ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

```
C:\Users\Streaming>ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy ffmpeg version N-52941-g13cb6ed Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on May 9 2013 17:24:42 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC) configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrn b --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libr tmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheo ra --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-li bvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --ena ble-zlib libavutil 52. 30.100 / 52. 30.100 libavcodec 55. 7.100 / 55. 7.100 libavformat 55. 4.101 / 55. 4.101 libavdevice 55. 0.100 / 55. 0.100 libavfilter 3. 63.101 / 3. 63.101 libswscale 2. 3.100 / 2. 3.100 libswresample 0. 17.102 / 0. 17.102 libpostproc 52. 3.100 / 52. 3.100 [dshow @ 0000000000306d00] DirectShow video devices [dshow @ 0000000000306d00] "Blackmagic WDM Capture" [dshow @ 0000000000306d00] "Decklink Video Capture" [dshow @ 0000000000306d00] DirectShow audio devices [dshow @ 0000000000306d00] "Line In (High Definition Audio " [dshow @ 0000000000306d00] "Decklink Audio Capture" [dshow @ 0000000000306d00] "Microphone (Total Recorder WDM " dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

ffmpeg -list_options true -f dshow -i video="Decklink Video Capture"

```
C:\Users\Streaming>ffmpeg -list_options true -f dshow -i video="Decklink Video C apture" ffmpeg version N-52941-g13cb6ed Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on May 9 2013 17:24:42 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC) configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrn b --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libr tmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheo ra --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-li bvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --ena ble-zlib libavutil 52. 30.100 / 52. 30.100 libavcodec 55. 7.100 / 55. 7.100 libavformat 55. 4.101 / 55. 4.101 libavdevice 55. 0.100 / 55. 0.100 libavfilter 3. 63.101 / 3. 63.101 libswscale 2. 3.100 / 2. 3.100 libswresample 0. 17.102 / 0. 17.102 libpostproc 52. 3.100 / 52. 3.100 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] DirectShow video device options [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] Pin "Capture" [dshow @ 00000000002fa080]
pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=720x486 fps=29.97 max s =720x486 fps=29.97 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=720x486 fps=23.976 max s=720x486 fps=23.976 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=720x576 fps=25 max s=72 0x576 fps=25 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=1920x1080 fps=23.976 ma x s=1920x1080 fps=23.976 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=1920x1080 fps=24 max s= 1920x1080 fps=24 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=1920x1080 fps=25 max s= 1920x1080 fps=25 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=1920x1080 fps=29.97 max s=1920x1080 fps=29.97 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080]
pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=1920x1080 fps=30 max s= 1920x1080 fps=30 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=1280x720 fps=50 max s=1 280x720 fps=50 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080]
pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=1280x720 fps=59.9402 ma x s=1280x720 fps=59.9402 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] pixel_format=uyvy422 min s=1280x720 fps=60.0002 ma x s=1280x720 fps=60.0002 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] vcodec=v210 min s=720x486 fps=29.97 max s=720x486 fps=29.97 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] vcodec=v210 min s=720x486 fps=23.976 max s=720x486 fps=23.976 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080]
vcodec=v210 min s=720x576 fps=25 max s=720x576 fps =25 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] vcodec=v210 min s=1920x1080 fps=23.976 max s=1920x 1080 fps=23.976 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080]
vcodec=v210 min s=1920x1080 fps=24 max s=1920x1080 fps=24 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] vcodec=v210 min s=1920x1080 fps=25 max s=1920x1080 fps=25 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] vcodec=v210 min s=1920x1080 fps=29.97 max s=1920x1 080 fps=29.97 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] vcodec=v210 min s=1920x1080 fps=30 max s=1920x1080 fps=30 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] vcodec=v210 min s=1280x720 fps=50 max s=1280x720 f ps=50 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080]
vcodec=v210 min s=1280x720 fps=59.9402 max s=1280x 720 fps=59.9402 [dshow @ 00000000002fa080] vcodec=v210 min s=1280x720 fps=60.0002 max s=1280x 720 fps=60.0002 video=Decklink Video Capture: Immediate exit requested
```

Comment: I think the default if you use those devices should be "The default", NB there's also more "native" decklink option these days [I believe]

Comment: `-f decklink -i "BlackMagic SDI (1)@3"` made it work for us (capturing from the `@3`rd port). The `-f dshow` method tried to open the input device twice which failed due to it already be opened.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the settings of your input format for it to work. Have a look at this [article](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1126).

If it does not fully resolved your issue please try this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212047/ffmpeg-command-line-for-capturing-and-recording-audio-and-video-in-720p-from-d).